# Linux Where to Store program icon

Tags: linux, debian, icons, gtk, deb

I'm trying to make a simple test gtk+ program and an installable .deb file for it. I made the program and I'm currently using [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/easy-way-to-create-a-debian-package-and-local-package-repository) to turn it into a .deb. but what I can't find out is where to put the custom logo for the program. I also want to know how I would need to change the code to fit this. I have the icon stored in the same directory as the source code but when i take the binary out of the folder with the icon the icon doesn't show.

Comment: Icons seem go into /usr/share/icons/ (one PNG per size, or a single SVG)

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe how obvious it was. I literally spent an hour picking apart programs and researching the fhs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icons go in `/usr/share/icons/` (one PNG per size, or a single SVG). Official specs are [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html).